# how to find out a MST of a given graph, which must include the edges from set A

Tags: greedy

Given a graph G = (V,E) and a set of edges A(which is a subset of E)

How to find a minimum spanning tree that must include the edges in A?

Comment: "How to find a minimum spanning tree that must include the edges in A?" That might be impossible, what if no MST use all of the edges in A? Perhaps you mean find the spanning tree whose total costs is minimal, subject to the constraint that it includes the edges in A. But, the resulting tree wouldn't necessarily be an MST.

Comment: In any event, Kruskal's algorithm seems like it is trivially modifiable to apply to this case. Just start Kruskal with the edges in A already chosen.